# Prevent a Windows forms textbox control from being accessible to a screen reader

Tags: winforms, accessibility

I have a Windows forms application that is being updated to support Accessibility clients like NVDA (screen reader) and I have one control, a textbox that I do not wish the screen reader to interact with.  It makes a mess of it. I can exclude it in the tab order of the form but if the user goes to it in another way (mouse etc) the mess remains.
Is there a way to exclude a control from interacting with a screen reader?
Thanks

Comment: So sighted users can type stuff into the textbox but visually impaired users can't?  Isn't that a huge accessibility issue, allowing some users to access an element but not others?  If an element doesn't work well with a screen reader, I would encourage you to fix the element instead of hiding it. Can you post your code?

Comment: No the code is extensive. Basically if you click on a character in the text box, it becomes selected and then you can use the up down keys to change the value or the right left to change the digit.  The screen reader keeps reading the whole thing, and then says the characters that are selected and then the ones unselected.  It's a mess.  If I can do this myself with .net speech, I can make it far better. Thus I want to disable the screen reader from reading that control